# Old view snapshot overlays today extension after crash

Tags: swift, ios10, today-extension, ios10-today-widget

After iOS 10.1 I have stumbled upon a weird issue with my Today Extension.

My extension consists of a UITableViewController.
If it for any reason crashes, it will show the message 'Unable to load'.
It will then recreate itself, but when it does it is overlayed with a static snapshot of the view.

It seems like the widget creates a snapshot, loads it, then reloads the TableViewController on top of it. It stays like this until the device is restarted.

The bug is also present on iOS 10.1.1.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue using UITableView inside UIViewController. Sometimes the snapshot is kinda shifted (like with default widget margin insets) so I see multiple instances of my views. Any progress on this?

Comment: Check if the memory requirement of the widget is not exceeding from that is provided. In this case also the system terminates the extension.